# How to do a multiple include in Magnolia CMS?

Tags: yaml, magnolia

On my sampleDialog.yaml, I want to include multiple files that contains different types of fields.

SampleDialog.yaml

This one is working as expected it loads all the fields on that file.

```
label: Sample
form:
  properties:!include:/sample-files/file1.yaml
```

But if I try to include multiple files, it is not working.

I already tried different formats like:

```
label: Sample
form:
  properties:
    - !include:/sample-files/file1.yaml
    - !include:/sample-files/file2.yaml

label: Sample
form:
  properties:
    !include:/sample-files/file1.yaml
    !include:/sample-files/file2.yaml

label: Sample
form:
  properties:
    !include: "/sample-files/file1.yaml"
    !include: "/sample-files/file2.yaml"
```

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Please see example below on how you can do that, please note that the files that are used as **"includes"** in the example are created with idea to be reused so the field/prop is defined within the dialog.

- Under **properties** define fields that you want to use into the dialog.
- Include the defined fileds into some specific **tab** from dialog definition.

Dialog definition example:

```
!inherit:global-elements:components/link

form:
  properties:
    iconType:
      !include:/webmasters-light-module/dialogs/includes/iconSwitchableField.yaml
    bodyStyle:
      !include:/webmasters-light-module/dialogs/components/heroSection/style/bodyStyle.yaml  
  layout:
    $type: tabbedLayout
    tabs:
      - name: tabMain
        fields:
          - name: iconType
          - name: bodyStyle
```

Field definition example (used as include file):

```
$type: staticField
label: ''
value: Body Style Configuration
```